# How to read all the lines in a file and store them in a string

Tags: c, string, file

I am trying to read some commands which should be passed to my program from a file. The commands are on different lines, so I guess this means that they are separated by `\n` character. This is my command reading section:

```
FILE *fop;
char command[50];
fopen("mbr.op", "r");
while(!feof(fop))
{ 
    fscanf(fop,"%s[^\n]", command);
    printf("%s\n", command);
}
fclose(fop);
```

This prints some words that are in the file, but not all, and not in the expected order. How could I change this code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` and casting the result of `malloc` are two plagues descended upon the community of people learning C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open your file incorrectly (*it returns a* FILE pointer which is associated with the opened file), `fopen` should be used as this -

```
fop=fopen("mbr.op", "r");
```

And [`while(!feof(fop))` should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) .

You can write your loop as follows -

```
while(fscanf(fop,"%[^\n]%*c", command)==1)
{  
  printf("%s\n", command);
}
```

**Note** - Also check if file was opened successfully.

Comment: `fgets()` will save newline character read to the buffer, so you will get two newline character after each line in your code using `fgets()`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Hmm yes mention in question that separated by `'\n` , didn't paid attention . `fgets` will be inappropriate.

Comment: Your code using `fscanf()` won't work. It will [read only first line](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/i2bZCuqV89I0SCTd).

Comment: @MikeCAT new line character has to be taken care of .

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE *fop;
char command[50];
fop = fopen("mbr.op", "r"); /* get the file pointer */
if (fop == NULL) exit(1); /* check if the file successfully opened */
while(fscanf(fop,"%49[^\n]%*c", command) == 1) /* see notes after this code */
{ 
    printf("%s\n", command);
}
fclose(fop);
```

Notes on the usage of `fscanf()`:

- They say using `feof()` is not good.
- Yon won't need the `s`.
- Specify the maximum length to read to avoid buffer overflow.
- Added `%*c` to have it skip the newline character.

This code above won't work well if there are blank lines.
I think using `fgets()` is better to read lines.

```
FILE *fop;
char command[51]; /* added 1 byte to store the newline character */
fop = fopen("mbr.op", "r");
if (fop == NULL) exit(1);
while(fgets(command, sizeof(command), fop))
{
    /* remove the newline character */
    char* p;
    for(p = command; *p != '\0' && *p != '\n'; p++);
    *p = '\0';
    /* print what is read */
    printf("%s\n", command);
}
fclose(fop);
```